# Treeview databound function not working in kendoui

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am using kendo UI tree view widget control and I am not able to use `dataBound` functionality.

```
$("#treeview").kendoTreeview({
    dataSource: parent,
    expanded: true,
    dataBound: ondata,
    dataTextField: ["Parent", "Child"]
}).data("kendoTreeView");

function ondata() {
    alert("databound");
}
```

But the alert is not showing.
What's wrong with it? Am I missing any thing like script files or something?

Comment: kendoTreeview is wrong. Should be kendoTreeView.

Comment: @AtanasKorchev sorry i wrote mistake here. I actually write kendoTreeView only there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see it is actually working [here](http://jsbin.com/edamuj/120/edit): Check the differences with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo treeview dataBound event only trigger if the data source is local.

May be check your datasource (binding).

Comments from telerik

- "Basically current behavior is expected as currently the TreeView is
  bind to the data on the server side. Please note that the DataBound
  event is triggered only after binding data on the client side. "

(http://50.56.19.112/forums/databound-event-doesn't-fire#boLRI66aG2OF1P8AAFTdxQ)